# Cross domain LocalStorage with iframe

Tags: javascript, cookies, iframe, cors

My iframe is using the link of a website that has a login mechanism, when I'm logged in the website I am also logged in the iframe but on some others computer it doesnt work

I am using google chrome and i am injecting the iframe on a site (https://example1.com) using javascript like this :

```
const AppIframe = document.createElement("iframe");
AppIframe.id = "iframeA";
AppIframe.title = "iframeA";
AppIframe.src = https://example.com;
AppIframe.style.width = "100%";
AppIframe.style.height = "100%";

...

popup.appendChild(AppIframe);
```

I don't understand why I have different behaviour between one computer and an other.
I figured out that I have different localStorage cookies for the different computer i tried and the cookies that are missing in some case are the aws cognito cookies use for authentication.

I think it might have to be related with the CORS but I can't figure out how to solve my issue.

Do somebody have an idea of what could be the problem ?

Thank you for your answers !

Comment: `but on some others computer it doesnt work` ... WHat exactly doesn't work?

Comment: When I am on https://example.com I am logged but when I am on https://example1.com and I inject an iframe with https://example.com url i am not logged on example.com and the cognito authentication cookies is not in the localstorage of https://example.com @GetSet

Comment: This is not a bug. Its desired behavior. For security purposes. There are other secure mechanisms to communicate with an iframe, if you need to.